# Android Studio CountDownTimer

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I'm trying to implement a countdown widget for my application. I need help in writing the code in such a way that it starts with a button and automatically stops when the time is up which would then show a text,"Finished". Any help is greatly appreciated ! Thank You in Advance !

I have actually tried some code examples. Gradle is able to run successfully without any problems. However, when I hit the start button, nothing happens. Here are the codes that I used:

```
public class countdown extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonStart;
TextView textCounter;

MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);
            myCountDownTimer.start();
        }
    });

}
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textCounter.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textCounter.setText("Finished!");
    }


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your button click listener:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
  //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("finished!");
 }
}
.start();
```

Refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Comment: Hi there, still unable to run the application successfully. Here is the error found on logcat.     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Replace mTextField with textcounter